# Strange bit twiddling bug

Tags: c

I have a simple function:

```
int bitcount( unsigned );

int shiftbit( unsigned val ) {
    return (int)(~0U << (( sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT ) - bitcount(val)));
}
```

I'm counting the number of bits in an int and then creating a bitmask which has that number of bits left justified.  For example, 0xABCD has 10 bits set and returns the mask 0xFFC0000.

The function works great except when the bitcount is zero in which case I get -1, 0xffffffff when I should just be getting an empty bitmask, i.e. 0x0.  It's just not clear to me why it should work for every case except zero.

**Answer**

So I ended up changing the code as follows, which works fine and should be portable:

```
int shiftbit( unsigned val ) {
    int bCount = bitcount(val);
    return bCount ? (~0 << (( sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT ) - bCount)) : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result of a shift operation is undefined if the number of shifted bits is greater than *or equal* to the number of bits in the shifted value. So, shifting a 32-bit value by 32 isn't guaranteed to produce anything in particular.

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes: Either that, or perform the shift in a *wider* integral type and then cast it back. Shift `~0UL` or `~0ULL`, depending on which type is wider than `int` on your platform and then  cast it back to `unsigned int` after the shift. Also, bitwise operations are more appropriate with unsigned types. Your usage of signed `int` doesn't look too good, unless you have a good reason to use a signed type.

Comment: @AndreyT:  That's probably not as portable as just checking for a zero bit count explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Because in C the result is undefined if you shift an operand having a size of `x` bits by `x` bits. So for example `1 << 32` is undefined (assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`)

Answer (score 0):

In C, the result of a shift is implementation-dependent. With x86 processors, you can actually be sure that the shift operand is modulo-32 (in 32-bit mode). See page 3-623 of this document:

ftp://download.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/24319101.pdf

"The destination operand can be a register or a memory location. The count operand can be an
immediate value or register CL. **The count is masked to five bits**, which limits the count range
to 0 to 31. A special opcode encoding is provided for a count of 1"

Comment: That's the processor's shift operation, C's shift operation is still undefined in these cases on x86. For example, try doing it in a release build in Visual Studio 2010. Visual Studio will optimize "int v = 32; int a = -1 << v" to "a = 0".

Comment: The original 16 bit versions of the x86 series didn't mask the shift count. This means that we have binary compatible processors with a different result from the same machine code. Wonder why C left this undefined? :-)